# Скринсейвер с помощью Direct3D9

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

Начал осваивать *DirectX*  с помощью книжечки Михаила Фленова, воссоздал крутящийся куб и подумал, а почему бы не сделать из всего этого заставочку. Взял все разбросанные по разным файлам объявления и определения функций, все заголовочные файлы и совместил в одном общем файлике. Вот что в итоге вышло:

```
#ifdef UNICODE

#pragma comment(lib, "ScrnSavw.lib")

#else

#pragma comment(lib, "ScrnSave.lib")

#endif

#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include <ScrnSave.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

#define D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)

LPDIRECT3D9 Direct3D = NULL;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 DirectDevice = NULL;
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 VBuffer = NULL;
LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 IBuffer = NULL;

D3DXMATRIX WorldR;
D3DXMATRIX View;
RECT winRect;

UINT Time = 0;
FLOAT Angle = 0;
UINT timer_id;

//структура, описывающая вершину:
struct CUSTOMVERTEX {
    FLOAT X, Y, Z;
    DWORD Color;
};

//Массив вершин:
CUSTOMVERTEX CubeVertex[] =
{
    //куб
    //грань 1
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0x00ff0000 },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0x0000ff00 },
    { -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0x000000ff },
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0x00ffff00 },
    //грань 2
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0x0000ff00 },
    { -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0x000000ff },
    { -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ffff00 },
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0x0000ffff },
    //грань 3
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0x000000ff },
    { -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ffff00 },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0x0000ffff },
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ff00ff },
    //грань 4
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ffff00 },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0x0000ffff },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0x00ff00ff },
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0x00ff0000 },
    //грань 5
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0x0000ffff },
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0x00ff00ff },
    { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ff0000 },
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0x0000ff00 },
    //грань 6
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ff00ff },
    { -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ff0000 },
    { -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0x0000ff00 },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0x000000ff }
};

//Массив индексов:
unsigned short CubeIndex[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
    4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4,
    8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 8,
    12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 12,
    16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 16,
    20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 20
};
float iWidth = (float)winRect.right - (float)winRect.left;
float iHeight = (float)winRect.bottom - (float)winRect.top;
float Aspect = iWidth / iHeight;
float x = 1.0f / sqrt(2.0f);
float y = x;

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
LONG WINAPI ScreenSaverProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL WINAPI ScreenSaverConfigureDialog(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL WINAPI RegisterDialogClasses(HANDLE);

HRESULT DInit(HWND hWnd)
{
    if (FAILED(Direct3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION)))
        return E_FAIL;

    D3DDISPLAYMODE Display;
    if (FAILED(Direct3D->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &Display)))
    return E_FAIL;
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS Device;
ZeroMemory(&Device, sizeof(Device));
//Device.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
Device.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_R5G6B5;
Device.BackBufferHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
Device.BackBufferWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
Device.Windowed = FALSE;
Device.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
Device.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = Display.RefreshRate;
Device.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT;

if (FAILED(Direct3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd, D3DCREATE_MIXED_VERTEXPROCESSING | D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED, &Device, &DirectDevice)))
    return E_FAIL;
DirectDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);
//(*DirectDevice)->SetRenderState(D3DRS_AMBIENT, 0x00ffffff);
DirectDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_CW);

return S_OK;
}

HRESULT ObjInit()
{
VOID *vBuf;
VOID *iBuf;

if (FAILED(DirectDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX)*24, 0, D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &VBuffer, 0)))
    return E_FAIL;

if (FAILED(VBuffer->Lock(0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX) * 24 , (void**)&vBuf, 0)))
    return E_FAIL;
memcpy(vBuf, CubeVertex, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX) * 24 );
VBuffer->Unlock();

if (FAILED(DirectDevice->CreateIndexBuffer(sizeof(short)*36, 0, D3DFMT_INDEX16, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &IBuffer, 0)))
    return E_FAIL;

if (FAILED(IBuffer->Lock(0, sizeof(short) * 36 , (void**)&iBuf, 0)))
    return E_FAIL;
memcpy(iBuf, CubeIndex, sizeof(short) * 36 );
IBuffer->Unlock();

return S_OK;
}

VOID Matrix(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 DirectDevice, D3DXMATRIX World, D3DXMATRIX     View, float Aspect)
{
D3DXMATRIX Projection;

DirectDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &World);
DirectDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &View);
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&Projection, D3DX_PI / 4, Aspect, 0.25f, 10000.0f);
DirectDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &Projection);
}

LONG WINAPI ScreenSaverProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &winRect);
    timer_id = SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 1000, NULL);
    if (FAILED(DInit(hWnd)))
        return FALSE;
    //Иинциализация объекта:
    else if (FAILED(ObjInit()))
        return FALSE;
    break;
case WM_TIMER:
    Time = timeGetTime() % 5000;
    Angle = Time * (2.0f * D3DX_PI) / 5000.0f;
    WorldR =
    {
        cos(Angle * 2) + (1 - cos(Angle * 2))*x*x, (1 - cos(Angle * 2))*x*y, sin(Angle * 2)*y, 0,
        (1 - cos(Angle * 2))*x*y, cos(Angle * 2) + (1 - cos(Angle * 2))*y*y, -sin(Angle * 2)*x, 0,
        -sin(Angle * 2)*y, sin(Angle * 2)*x, cos(Angle * 2), 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1
    };

    View =
    {
        abs(cos(Angle)), 0, 0, 0,
        0, abs(cos(Angle)), 0, 0,
        0, 0, abs(cos(Angle)), 0,
        0, 0, 5, 1
    };

    DirectDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0, 20, 20, 20), 1.0f, 0);
    DirectDevice->BeginScene();
    Matrix(DirectDevice, WorldR, View, Aspect);
    DirectDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX);
    DirectDevice->SetStreamSource(0, VBuffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
    DirectDevice->SetIndices(IBuffer);
    DirectDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_FILLMODE, D3DFILL_WIREFRAME);
    DirectDevice->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 24, 0, 12);
    DirectDevice->EndScene();
    DirectDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    if (timer_id)
        KillTimer(hWnd, timer_id);
    if (IBuffer != NULL)
        IBuffer->Release();
    if (VBuffer != NULL)
        VBuffer->Release();
    if (DirectDevice != NULL)
        DirectDevice->Release();
    if (Direct3D != NULL)
        Direct3D->Release();
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefScreenSaverProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
}
BOOL WINAPI ScreenSaverConfigureDialog(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
return FALSE;
}

BOOL WINAPI RegisterDialogClasses(HANDLE hInst)
{
return TRUE;
}
```

После того, как все это скомпилировалось, было подвержено изменинию разрешения, а также помещено в папку `System32`, настал момент установить заставочку. Но в результате сразу после установки выскакивает сообщение о прекращении работы программы, а ее отладка не позволяет мне судить о причине подобного поведения, ибо отладка добирается до дизассемблированного кода. Что интересно, если поменять

```
Device.Windowed = TRUE;
```

на

```
Device.Windowed = FALSE;
```

то ошибка исчезнет, но при запуске скринсейвера будет только черный экран.
Я не знаю, как это можно исправить, да и в чем ошибка честно признаться не могу понять. Надеюсь, что кто-то сможет помочь..

Comment: Пиши логи и лови unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @cpp_user никогда не доходило до того, чтобы пришлось писать логи ) Немного поколдовав, мой простенький лог и пара часов в отладке дали следующее - при полноэкранном отображении падает CreateDevice из-за переполнения буфера. Если поменять на оконный режим, то все функционирует, таймер тикает, функции вызываются, но ничего не происходит. Черный экран. Я считаю, что тайна кроется в D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS но как не менял данные этой структуры результат тот же. Спасибо за идею с логами, почувствовал себя более менее программистом )

Comment: @cpp_user вот еще что, после установки оконного режима ошибок нет, лог показывает работу функций, ничего правда при этом не отображается. Но изменение цвета, передаваемого аргументом для функции Clear вносит изменения в программу и теперь я гляжу не на черный экран а на красный экран. Возможно какая то проблема с буферами вершин и индексов, а может и нет, это лишь догадки.

Comment: Как минимум нужен еще параметр BackBufferCount, удостоверился бы что формат D3DFMT_R5G6B5 в полноэкранном режиме поддерживается и заменил бы GetSystemMetrics(...) на константы из списка доступных видеорежимов видеокарты. P.S. По хорошему прежде чем устанавливать какие то параметры нужно удостовериться что видеокарта эти параметры поддерживает.

Comment: @cpp я ведь этот код не с небес брал. У меня есть проект с этим же кодом, но только не для скринсейвера и в нем все нормально, куб есть, он крутится, следовательно и формат я так считаю поддерживается.

Comment: Ты не прав, это все книжные примеры они очень упрощенные для демонстрации чтобы не перегружать внимание читателя - в реальной жизни все куда сложнее.

Comment: @cpp здесь соглашусь, книжные примеры порой даже убоги. Неловко просить, но раз уж я знаком только с книжными примерами, где нет столь интересных и полезных вещей, да и понятия не имею как вытаскивать доступные для видеокарты режимы и форматы, то можно небольшой примерчик?

Comment: Примерчиков полно в DirectX SDK.

Comment: @cpp_user так уж вышло, что один из примерчиков SDK уже отображал доступные видеорежимы и форматы. Но даже выставив все, что поддерживает моя видеокарта, я не могу запустить фуллскрин, выскакивает ошибка, а отладка говорит о переполнении буфера. Отказываюсь от фуллскрина, ставлю Device.Windowed = True и ошибка пропадает. Вот только все равно черный экран